# Nested attributes not being inserted into table Rails and AngularJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, strong-parameters

I have one problem with Ruby on Rails 4, Method create and Strong Parameters, when sending a post with nested values, my app save the object father correct, but the children save only create_at and update_at, below my code:

1. My JSON sending

   ```
   {
   "CliRazao"=>"FORNECEDOR 1.", 
   "CliCNPJ"=>"78456896000185", 
   "CliEmail"=>"contato@contato.com.br", 
   "CliObs"=>"Teste\nTeste\nTEste", 
   "enderecos"=>[
       {
           "EndCEP"=>"17456789", 
           "EndTipo"=>"E", 
           "EndLogradouro"=>"RUA DOS TUCUNARES", 
           "EndNumero"=>"78", 
           "EndBairro"=>"JARDIM AQUARIUS", 
           "EndCidade"=>"MARILIA", 
           "EndEstado"=>"SP"
       }, 
       {
           "EndCEP"=>"18456123", 
           "EndTipo"=>"C", 
           "EndLogradouro"=>"RUA AFONSO PENA", 
           "EndNumero"=>"78", 
           "EndBairro"=>"JARDIM NOVO MUNDO", 
           "EndCidade"=>"MARILIA", 
           "EndEstado"=>"SP"
       }
   ], 
   "CliERP"=>"C-00125", 
   "cliente"=>
       {
           "CliERP"=>"C-00125", 
           "CliRazao"=>"FORNECEDOR 1", 
           "CliCNPJ"=>"78456896000185", 
           "CliEmail"=>"contato@contato.com.br", 
           "CliObs"=>"Teste\nTeste\nTEste"
       }
   ```

   }
2. My Model cliente.rb (Father)

   class Cliente < ActiveRecord::Base
       has_many :enderecos, autosave: true

   ```
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :enderecos
   ```

   end
3. My Model endereco.rb (Child)

   class Endereco < ActiveRecord::Base
       belongs_to :cliente
   end
4. My controller

   class ClientesController < ApplicationController
       def index
           @clientes = Cliente.all
       end

   ```
   def findById
       @clientes = Cliente.find(params[:id]);
   end

   def create
       @cliente = Cliente.new(cliente_params);
       @cliente.enderecos.build(cliente_params[:enderecos_attributes]);
       logger.debug "Enderecos => #{cliente_params}"

       respond_to do |format|
           if @cliente.save
               format.json { render :show, status: :created }
           else
               format.json { render json: @cliente.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
           end
       end
   end

   def update
   end

   private
   def cliente_params
       params.require(:cliente).permit(:CliERP, :CliRazao, :CliCNPJ, :CliEmail, :CliObs, enderecos_attributes: [:EndTipo, :EndLogradouro, :EndNumero, :EndBairro, :EndCidade, :EndCEP, :EndEstado])
   end
   ```

   end

The enderecos are not inserted in my database and no exception is thrown.

Thanks!

Comment: Because the json what you sending has a wrong key `"enderecos" => ....` it should be `"enderecos_attributes"=>....`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attributes aren't actually nested. If they were the `json` for enderecos would be inside cliente.

For nested attributes you need several things.

1. You need `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, which you have.
2. In our form you need to use `fields_for` for the nested attributes
3. In your new action you need to `build` the nested resource
4. In your controller you need to add the nested attributes to your permitted params with `.permit(:enderecos_attributes => [:attribute_name, :another_attribute_name]`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks!
My JSON was wrong , as you said he was not nested.